# Random normal distribution generator comparison

Tags: c, performance, optimization, random

So i've written a couple random number generators for a project that relies on generating normally distributed random numbers. I have written a couple of different implementations of the generator - namely Box-Muller method, Marsaglia's Polar method and the Inverse cumulative distribution approximation method. I've compared them in terms of speed and it turns out Inverse method is the fastest of the 3, is this expected, or did I mess up while writing the other two? I know numpy used the Polar method for a long time, so i believe it should be the fastest of the 3?

I compiled using gcc9.3.0 and used -O3 flag.

here are the codes for the generators:

```
struct gaussGenState 
{
    float gauss;
    int has_gauss;
};

void initializeGauss(struct gaussGenState *state)
{
    state->has_gauss = 0;
    state->gauss = 0.0;
}

float gauss(struct gaussGenState *state)
{
    /*
        Implementation of Marsaglia's polar method for calculating normally distributed 
        gaussian variables
        seeding of rand needs to be done outside of function (with srand())
    */
    if (state->has_gauss){
        const float temp = state->gauss;
        state->has_gauss = 0;
        state->gauss = 0.0;
        return temp;
    }   
    else {
        float f, x1, x2, r2;

        do {
            x1 = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 2 - 1;
            x2 = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 2 - 1;
            r2 = x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
        } while (r2 >= 1.0 || r2 == 0.0);

        f = sqrt(-2.0 * log(r2) / r2);

        state->gauss = f * x1;
        state->has_gauss = 1;
        return f * x2;
    }
}

float gaussbm(struct gaussGenState *state)
{
    /*
        Implementation of Box-Muller method for calculating normally distributed gaussian 
        variables
        seeding of rand needs to be done outside of function (with srand())
    */
    if (state->has_gauss){
        const float temp = state->gauss;
        state->has_gauss = 0;
        state->gauss = 0.0;
        return temp;
    }
    else {
        float u, v, f1, f2;

        u = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX);
        v = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX);

        f1 = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u));
        f2 = 2*M_PI*v;

        state->gauss = f1 * cos(f2);
        state->has_gauss = 1;
        return f1 * sin(f2);
    }
}

float gaussInv(void)
{
    /*
        Implementation of Inverse cumulative distribution method for calculating normally 
        distributed gaussian variables
        Approximation relative error less than 1.15 x 10e-9 in the entire region.
        seeding of rand needs to be done outside of function (with srand())
    */
    float p, q, r;

    float a[6] = {-3.969683028665376e+01,  2.209460984245205e+02,
                    -2.759285104469687e+02,  1.383577518672690e+02,
                    -3.066479806614716e+01,  2.506628277459239e+00};
    float b[5] = {-5.447609879822406e+01,  1.615858368580409e+02,
                    -1.556989798598866e+02,  6.680131188771972e+01,
                    -1.328068155288572e+01};
    float c[6] = {-7.784894002430293e-03, -3.223964580411365e-01,
                    -2.400758277161838e+00, -2.549732539343734e+00,
                     4.374664141464968e+00,  2.938163982698783e+00};
    float d[4] = { 7.784695709041462e-03,  3.224671290700398e-01,
                    2.445134137142996e+00,  3.754408661907416e+00};

    p = ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX);

    if (p < 0.02425){
        q = sqrt(-2*log(p));
        return ((((((c[0]*q+c[1])*q+c[2])*q+c[3])*q+c[4])*q+c[5]) /
               ((((d[0]*q+d[1])*q+d[2])*q+d[3])*q+1));
    }

    if ((1-0.02425) < p){
        q = sqrt(-2*log(1-p));
        return -((((((c[0]*q+c[1])*q+c[2])*q+c[3])*q+c[4])*q+c[5]) / 
                ((((d[0]*q+d[1])*q+d[2])*q+d[3])*q+1));
    }

    q = p - 0.5;
    r = q*q;
    return ((((((a[0]*r+a[1])*r+a[2])*r+a[3])*r+a[4])*r+a[5])*q /
           (((((b[0]*r+b[1])*r+b[2])*r+b[3])*r+b[4])*r+1));
}
```

Comment: If the question is "are algorithms using look-up tables generally faster" then the answer is: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the implementation of **`rand` is often pretty slow** and using a **slow division** by `RAND_MAX` with a `float` cast is not going to help either. As a result, it is not surprising that the `gauss` and `gaussbm` implementations (which call at least `rand` twice) are actually slower than `gaussInv` (which call `rand` once).

Moreover, `gauss` is slow also because of the bad *predictability* of the while loop (processors are often faster on predictable loops and conditionals), and `gaussbm` is slow also because of the *expensive `cos`/`sin` trigonometric function*.

While `gaussInv` should be faster than the two others, it can be still improved. One way it to use **vectorization** and a custom *optimized random function*. Indeed, most processors can work on many floating-point at a time thanks to *SIMD instruction* and this function can makes use of them (although this is not straightforward). Most mainstream x86-64 processors can work on 8 floats in a row (using AVX/AVX2) and few recent processors can even compute up to 16 floats in a row (using AVX-512). Note that `gaussbm` could be vectorized too.

For scalar implementations, *lookup tables* can be used to speed up the computation although the throughput of the fastest scalar implementation will likely be significantly less than the one of any optimized vectorised implementation on modern mainstream processors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer first of all :) I'm not working with a very modern processor, I'm implementing this on ARM Cortex-M0/M1 and I will be using ARM Compiler 5 :( - I'm just prototyping with gcc for now . Anyways, yeah, I agree, rand() is kinda slow, in the meantime I changed it to Marsaglia SHR3, which did make the difference between Polar and Inverse quite a bit smaller - and also both a nice bit faster! Any pointers with vectorization? 
I'm trying to implement the Ziggurat algorithm right now and see how well that performs.

Comment: Hi. Indeed, these types of processors are both very minimalist and very old (~12 years). Thus, I do not think it supports Neon or any SIMD instruction set... Actually, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Cortex-M0), it seems it does not even support hardware floating-point computation at all! If the code can be executed, this is likely because of a slow emulation... Even the integer divisions are restricted. In this case, using *lookup tables*, *fixed-point precision* and tricky integers hacks should be the best solution here...

Comment: Hey, just an update, I've implemented the ziggurat algorithm and it outperforms all of these in terms of speed - lookup tables speed things up quite a bit! Thanks for your help!